# Photos can't be deleted from iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, photos

There are some photos on my iPhone 6 plus that I want to get rid of but I can't. When I click the photo the trash-can disappears. When I click *edit* a note pops up saying these photos are not editable.

How can I delete them?

Answer (score 1):

If the photos were put by syncing with iTunes you can't delete them using iPhone.

To delete photos and/or albums that were copied to your iPhone by syncing with your computer are deleted by doing another sync.

- Start iTunes on the computer and connect your phone.
- Select your phone in iTunes and select the Photos tab.
- Then DESELECT the items you no long want on the Phone.
- Then click on Apply or sync.

The photos or albums will be removed from your iPhone but they will remain on your computer.

Answer (score -1):

Yup, if they are on the stream then you can delete it on your phone. Doing another sync on iTunes is required.